# Is /dev/tmp pseudofile a good idea, or perhaps there is sth like that already?

Tags: linux-kernel, udev

I am using an application that stores its cache in a file. The thing is that I don't care about the data, so I would like the file to be removed right after the application finishes. A perfect use case for a temporary file.

**Problem** - the application is being called from a framework that is embedded inside another framework. So I don't have a place, where I could create the file upfront easily, and if the file does not exist (it can be empty), the application refuses to start.

**Solution (as I imagine it)** - I would like to have */dev/tmp* file, that would help me to fool the application, similarly as we use */dev/null*, */dev/zero*

How I imagine this to work?

1. application opens */dev/tmp*
2. kernel creates a temporary file in */tmp* directory and gives to the app a file descriptor pointing to it
3. when file descriptor gets closed, kernel removes automatically the file

Do you know if there is a way I could achieve this behaviour?

**EDIT**

Apparently there is no such functionality. So forget about my problem (I will solve it somehow) and let me rephrase the question.

Nowadays applications handle temporary files on their own. They create them and remove afterwards. If there would be a */dev/tmp* pseudofile, then kernel would manage temporary files for us (even if an application would crash). Do you think it would make sense?

Comment: IMHO: solving bad application design by introducing kernel driver which is even worse is awful idea.

Comment: true. But don't you think that having a pseudofile like this would solve all hassle with temporary files in general ? Think how many bash script create temporary files. This all could be replaced with /dev/tmp

Comment: This seems likely to be an XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/). Are there any parts of this system that *you* control?

Comment: @LukaszGuminski: But sometimes you need two temporary files So you'll need `/dev/tmp/N` :)

Comment: @myaut nope. Just one. And every time an application opens it, a new temporary file would be created. That's why I called it a pseudofile.

Comment: @GilHamilton the thing is that all the tools are provided by 3rd parties. And I am integrating them together.

Comment: Why can you not simply wrap the application with a small script that does "`touch /tmp/whatever; exec original_app`"? That would be much easier than writing what sounds like a quite complex kernel driver.

Comment: @GilHamilton but then I need to provide all developers in my company with the wrapper, which means I need to repackage the original binary, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: The wrapper could itself be created post-installation with another simple script (`mv app original_app; echo -e '#!/bin/bash\ntouch /tmp/whatever; exec original_app' >app; chmod +x app`). If you go the driver route, though, you'll need to provide your new driver to the developers too. And potentially rebuild it and repackage it every time there's a kernel security update. Good luck

Comment: @GilHamilton unless it would be added to the kernel. By that time of course I will solve my problem in some way. But it is not the point.

I am asking you for an opinion if the idea is good. Imagine how many applications handle temporary files. And they all do that in their unique ways. It all would be gone if there would be a pseudofile like this, and then the kernel would manage temporary files for us.

Comment: Yes, but creating a temporary file is no more difficult than opening one. And management requirements of temporary files is likely to be different for each application. For example, some applications create temporary files which they place data in, then pass on to a subordinate command. So they may need a file name that can be addressed by a separate process. (I suppose the idea is not completely without merit but it seems to be a "general purpose solution" to a very application-specific problem.)

Comment: Expanding on my last comment: This isn't a terrible idea and if such a facility existed, I could see myself using it in some situations. OTOH, the problem it solves is a small one and generally not difficult to solve in other ways. Note, for example, that tmpfile(3) provides a nearly identical capability.

Comment: @GilHamilton Managing a temporary file is more difficult than just opening, because it needs to be removed afterwards, and when an application crashes it has no chance to do it. Whereas kernel is always there and if it would take the responsibility, the problem would be gone.

But you have a valid point about passing file names between processes. However sharing data by passing file names instead of file descriptors does not sound like a good practice.